# How to automate scrape video URL when I must click Play Button before with Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape video URL using Beautifulsoup4.
But until i click the play button in browser, i can't get the URL.
so.. i must click the play button first to get the URL.

like the example bellow,

```
<div class="main">
  <div id="videocontainer" class="type-BLOGGER_UPLOADED">
    <div class="thumbnail-holder" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://video.google.com/ThumbnailServer2?app=blogger&amp;contentid=eae413efa246e05e&amp;offsetms=5000&amp;itag=w320&amp;expire=1545206575&amp;sigh=3WvNZuyWgKCUk7-6tgOjwq3EEZE&quot;);"></div>
    <div class="play-button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There I have `<div class="play-button"></div>` before i click the play button.

And when I click the play button, I got this:
[image]
Now I have children in the `<div class="main">` parent and the `<div class="play-button"></div>` disappeared.

And the element what I need is in the:

```
<video tabindex="-1" class="video-stream html5-main-video" controlslist="nodownload" style="width: 640px; height: 380px; left: 0px; top: -380px;" src="https://r5---sn-uxa3vhnxa-jb3k.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=eae413efa246e05e&amp;itag=18&amp;source=blogger&amp;mm=31&amp;mn=sn-uxa3vhnxa-jb3k&amp;ms=au&amp;mv=m&amp;pl=18&amp;ei=v5gZXI7MKo_m-gOy5LmwCw&amp;susc=bl&amp;mime=video/mp4&amp;dur=1435.364&amp;lmt=1544960809940468&amp;mt=1545181277&amp;ip=182.0.138.129&amp;ipbits=0&amp;expire=1545210175&amp;sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ei,susc,mime,dur,lmt&amp;signature=243471695096D7770FF491ADE53D9EC8B5F536A8310D44DB7592967C81EBC52E.4DD5265799EBC873AC3AA72F263D2BF93EABEB76BFB0BE8BF117B13668E91601&amp;key=us0&amp;cpn=Vq-BvZw7ez-BtG70&amp;c=WEB_EMBEDDED_PLAYER&amp;cver=20181215"></video>
```

But, I can't get it before I click the Play Button, so how to do it in Beautifulsoup4 or should I automate to click the Play Button, if so.. how to do that..?

Comment: You will likely need something like selenium if you have to interact with the page in that way. Provide the url and update with your coding attempts.

Comment: I have try selenium @QHarr, but when i try it the selenium open up the browser.
I load about 600+ video URL, so i think this not efficient way.

Comment: Because it's worth mentioning: "efficient" is relative to overall effort. If you are looking at 600 videos and it takes 5 seconds per video, that would be 50 minutes of runtime. Even if it took 10 seconds per video that would still only be 1h40m So the question is: would it take you longer than an hour and 40 minutes to figure out the problem and the write code to solve it, which may itself take an additional 10 minutes to run once you are done?

Comment: As for how you could go about solving the problem, I would look at the javascript being used on the page to propagate the url link: if that link is stored somewhere on the page as a variable or retrieved via an api/ajax call that you can replicate (or otherwise is obtained through a function you can replicate in python) then you will be able to get the link that way.